# Getting specific properties from an object child

Tags: c#, reflection

Struggled to come up with a decent way to ask/title this question, but will try and illustrate it as best I can.

I am working with a data structure something like this:

```
public Foo
{
     public Bar Bar {get;set;}
}

public Bar
{
    public SubTypeA TypeA {get;set;}
    public SubTypeB TypeB {get;set;}
    ...
}

public SubTypeA
{
    public int Status {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

Note that I am unable to change the data structure for this.

There are many different types in the `Bar` class, which all have different properties within them, but common to all of them is the property of `Status`.

What I need to do, is given an object of type `Foo`, is record the statuses for every item in the `Bar` object within it.  Not every `SubType` is going to have a value every time though, some could be null.

I can sort of manage it by using a recursive function like below to loop through all the properties.  It isn't ideal though I don't think as the loop could get quite large as there could be a lot of properties on each `SubType`.

```
private void GetProperties(Type classType, object instance)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in classType.GetProperties())
    {

        object value = property.GetValue(instance, null);
        if (value != null) 
        {
            if (property.Name == "Status")
            {
                Record(classType, value);
            }
            GetProperties(property.PropertyType, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Is this about the only approach that there is for such a problem?

EDIT: Going by the answer given by Selman22, I have come up with another issue wherein I am trying to create an anonymous object based on the status and name of object.

```
var z = instance.GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Select(x => new 
                { 
                    status = x.GetValue(instance).GetType().GetProperty("status").GetValue(x, null), 
                    name = x.Name 
                })
            .ToList();
```

This is throwing an error of `Object does not match target type.` when trying to retrieve the value.  Is this possible in a 1 liner?

Comment: `Status` is integer, how it can be null?

Comment: it won't be... I said things like `SubTypeA` could be null

Comment: If nestedness is the same, then you don't need recursion, just a loop for `typeof(Bar).GetProperties()`.

Answer (score 2):

**Type** class contains **GetProperty(string name, BindingFlags method)** that you can use to retrieve specific property. Instead of looping through every property use this method.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperty(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getproperty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
// Get Type object of MyClass.
Type myType=typeof(MyClass);       
// Get the PropertyInfo by passing the property name and specifying the BindingFlags.
PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty("MyProperty", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Comment: Yes, I get that, but the type I am given is of type `Foo`, and I need access to properties from properties on `Foo`.  Can't realistically do this for every `SubType` on `Bar` class

Comment: Why can't you loop recursively through every subtype and check if it has "status" property get its value. Also if this code will be invoked often and performance is important for you, you can cache PropertyInfo instances that you get from GetProperty method in a Dictionary<Type,PropertyInfo>, so you don't have to call GetProperty  more than once per type. Once you get PropertyInfo it can be used multiple times with different instances of the same class.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all `Status` properties using `LINQ` instead of recursion:

```
var barInstance = typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bar").GetValue(fooInstance);

var statusProperties = barInstance.GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Select(x => x.GetValue(barInstance).GetType().GetProperty("Status"));
```

Comment: looks nice, would you be able to have a look at my above edit?